# How to get override style of a Polygon from GoogleMap v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a trouble of looking up the color that I previously set for a polygon on the google map.

First I do:

```
map2.data.setStyle(map, mStyle); //setting the polygon to white
```

then i did

```
map2.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, redStyle); // setting the polygon to red
```

when I look up

```
map2.data.getStyle().fillColor; // this return me white instead of red even I already set it.
```

here is my styling declaration:

```
mStyle={
  fillColor : white
}

redStyle={
  fillColor : red
}
```

I don't think `getStyle()` function get the override Style.

Please help.

Comment: The documentation for getStyle says "Gets the style for all features in the collection."  So given that all features have a fillColor of white, and you've only overwritten the style for one feature, I'm assuming it's using the original default.

Comment: Also you're passing two arguments to the setStyle function (`setStyle(map, mStyle)`), but the documentation indicates you only pass one

Comment: that is my question, is it possible for me to get the override Style of that particular feature. I am sure it return the original default just like you mentioned. But I want to retrieve the override one. Not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be late but I hope that it will help in future.
Each time you use map2.data.overrideStyle to override a particular style, you should use also Call the revertStyles() method to remove all style overrides.
See details at the  section 'Override default styles' on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#override_default_styles

Comment: well, even if this is correct, it does not answer the OP question.
the thing is, i need to get the overrides too, because i do several overrides, which i do not want to revert and use them as a base for other overrides. example: map with markers which show online/offline state which is updated regularly via xhr. if i hide "offline" markers, the xhr update-request displays the offline markers again, altough i have hidden them with a custom control. here i would need to get the recent style-overrides.

Comment: this might be relevant and kind of a solution to the OP question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191132/google-map-api-v3-check-if-geojson-feature-in-data-layer-is-visible