# Google Map API v3: check if geojson feature in data layer is visible

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I use filters to hide or show features/markers in the Data Layer. I try to check which markers are visible after filtering, and if one property of the feature matches one property of an existing polyline (in another json file); then I decide if I show or hide the polyline also.
How to know if a certain marker is visible?

Comment: How do you hide the features ?

Answer (score 4):

You could set a custom property on the feature and toggle it as you hide and show the feature:

```
feature.setProperty('visible', false);
```

This would have to be done in addition to the following to actually hide the feature:

```
map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {
  visible: false
});
```

Then get the property to see if it is visible:

```
feature.getProperty('visible');
```

That's what I ended up doing because I couldn't find a way to get the visible property when setting it on the feature itself with overrideStyle.